# Obscure text disable keyboard

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a textformfield when isObscure is true, in Android everything work normally but when I run on iPhone , I can not type anything. I don't know why it happens.

```
 TextFormField(
          obscureText: isObscure,
          key: passwordEntryKey,
          controller: TextEditingController()
            ..text = provider.data.password
            ..value = TextEditingValue(text: provider.data.password)
            ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: provider.data.password.length)),
          onChanged: (pass) {
            provider.data.password = pass;
          },
          onTap: () {
            SignUpPageState.of(context).changeScale(0.8);
          },
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return "Bạn phải điền mật khẩu";
            }
             return null;
          },
         )
```

Comment: Your code runs on my emulator of course I had to substitute dummy data for provider but doubt that would make a difference

Comment: What is your iOS version and which flutter branch are you in now? I am currently in the branch master.

Comment: flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 channel stable and iOS simulator 13.3

Comment: When I change to branch stable it worked. I think it might be an unfixed bug from flutter team

Comment: do you know why it happens?

Comment: what channel were you on seems to be something that has todo with the upgrade they just released https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to Stable branch seems to fix the problem

```
flutter channel stable
```